# How in a try/catch return something or null depending if it fails after a finite number of retries

Tags: javascript

In a NodeJs backend, I need to implement a function which tries for 10 times max to retrieve the data from a request.

The retry need to be waiting for 15s before hit again the request.

If on the first try the request succeed I have to return the data.

If it fails it is retiring 10 times and after that on the 10th time fails, has to return null.

My issue is with following function:

```
// Helper for the waiting
const sleep = (ms) => {
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
   setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
};

async function getData(documentId, log) {
  const MAX_RETRIES = 10;
  const timeout = 15000;

  for (let i = 0; i <= MAX_RETRIES; i += 1) {
    try {
      const { icfDocuments } = await request(
        CONSENT_SERVICE_URL,
        getICFDocumentRecipientsQuery,
        {
          documentId,
        }
      );
      // if the pdfUrl is present return the data
      if (icfDocuments.nodes[0].revision.pdfUrl) return icfDocuments;
    } catch (err) {
      log.debug('Waiting for retrieve the last revision pdfUrl', timeout, 'ms');
      await sleep(timeout);
      log.debug('Retrying', err.message, i);
    }
  }
  // What here ??? return data or null ???
  return null;
}
```

What I need to wait is that `pdfUrl` to be present in the data. Not to be null.
If it is null than should be retry max 10 times to see if we get that pdfUrl.
If that fails I return null.
If that success I return the data.

At the moment this above not really work and not sure how to make it correct to get the right output.

Comment: [Rxjs](https://rxjs.dev/) makes a good fist of this kind of complex async workflow.

Comment: Cannot introduce new packages into the code base at the moment so I need a different solution :(

Comment: Maybe the problem is you don't have an else statement when your checking the pdfUrl and sleeping there?

Comment: Are you sure that `request` throws ? Some http client libs only throw on 5XX, but you may be getting 4XX ?

Comment: The request is to GraphQL API service which is throwing errors when there are but in this case we just receive NULL for the pdfUrl because the worker require time to generate the pdf and send it to aws. So we don't get errors if it is null.